# css to hide the near div when this div is clicked (working for hover)

Tags: html, css

My code :

```
<div>
<div class='top-class'>
Header Name
</div>
<div class='body-class'>
This is body a
</div>
</div>


<div>
<div class='top-class'>
Another Header Name
</div>
<div class='body-class'>
Another body
</div>
</div>
```

css code I tried:

```
.top-class:hover + .body-class { display: block; } /* This is working */
```

But, I want that to happen when header is clicked. So, i tried this:

```
.top-class:visited + .body-class { display: block; } /* DIDNT work */
```

Comment: visited can only be on an A i guess. You're using div's

Comment: How does your first example work?  `.body-class` is a sibbling of `.top-class`, not a child.

Comment: Yeah, :visited is a pseudo-selector and only applies to anchors.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to use a little Javascript to do this with DIVs...

Comment: very sorry, for hover, + worked. not >

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo class "active" seems to do the job

```
.top-class:active + .body-class { display: block; background-color: red; }
```

You can check [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7FFD/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabindex` in you first div then it can  have focus event on.

```
<div class='top-class' tabindex=1>Header Name</div>
```

Then in css you test `focus` pseudo class

```
.top-class:focus + .body-class { display: block; background-color: red; }
```

[Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/HWUy2/2/)

Comment: This is nice, but when I click on any other part of the page, it is loosing its focus.

Comment: Of corse, but you want the div to desapear forever ? Im afraid you cant do this in pure CSS